# Sound unmutes automatically after switching applications

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, audio-volume

Whenever I press the mute button my sounds are muted successfully, unmuting works fine too.
But when I mute the volume and switch applications and it plays a sound, it's automatically unmuted again which is very annoying.
This also happens with applications in the background.
E.g: I hit the mute button, it's quite. But then a messenger receives a message or switch to browser and press play on YouTube and my system sound is unmuted again. And I can hear it.
When the first audio source is still running it stays quite.

I'm using Manjaro with with 5.9.3 kernel. Pulseaudio is 13.99.3. I tried setting the `flat-volumes = no` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and restarted the service without any effect.
I have no idea what else can cause this.

[image: What it looks like after muting.]